# Display an element on first page visit

Tags: javascript, session

I want that my site shows something the first time a user opens it. But the second time after he was on another site and goes back it should be hidden. I know that it is possible with sessionStorage but I have absolutely no clou how to do it. Here is my code:

````
var status2=false;

if (statusSession==="false")
{
  $("label").hide();
  $("select").hide();
  $("input").hide();
  $("button").hide();
  $("h1").html("Welcome Press Space To Start");
  $(document).on("keypress",function(){
    if(status2===false)
    {
      $("h1").hide();
      $("label").show();
      $("select").show();
      $("input").show();
      $("button").show();
      status2===true;
    }
  })
}```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SessionStorage gets wiped at the end of the session, so you want to use LocalStorage so that the info is still there when you browse to another site and come back.

Just try to grab the storage item, if it is not there it will be null, so then test it with an if statement and then set it for next time:

```
const hasVisited = localStorage.getItem('hasVisited');

if(!hasVisited) {

  localStorage.setItem('hasVisited', true)

  // Do something

} else {

  // Do something else

}
```

Here are the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API) for using the Storage API.